# Subclassing a class with a private default constructor in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Say I have class `A` with a private constructor, and class `B` that extends it:

```
public class A {
    private A() {}
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(){
        // error - there is no default constructor available in 'A'
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to call private constructors via Java Reflection, but how can I do it **in the `B` constructor**? Thanks.

Comment: If `B` extends `A` (which it doesn't in your example) and `A`'s constructor is private, it's simple: **you can't**. Take a look at the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.10).

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904355/how-to-resolve-implicit-super-constructor-classa-is-not-visible-must-explici

Comment: @Alex R, but still you can use Reflection to instantiate class A (though spec says you can't do it)

Comment: Will java (the compiler) recognize that though? If B extends A, the compiler requires that B call A's constructor in the first line of B's contructor

Comment: B could be an inner class though? Then it would work

Comment: @LeoLeontev Using this logic `private` is not `private` either.

Comment: Another good question is why do you want to do this.....

Comment: If A only has this one private constructor it should be declared final

Comment: To put the above comments another way: if the author of `A` knew what they were doing, the _reason_ they made it private is exactly to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: If class `A` has only a private constructor, then by its very definition it cannot be extended.

Comment: @DavidRTribble That's _almost_ true, but not quite. A nested class (within `A`) can still extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If class `B` extends `A` and `A`'s constructor is private, subclassing is not possible unless both classes are defined in the same file as inner classes (see [Preventing Instantiation of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.10)). That's because the constructor of the subclass does an (either explicit or implicit) `super()` call. A `super()` call is basically just a call to the matching constructor and if that constructor is declared `private`, this call is not possible from some outer class (e.g. one defined in a different file).